# I Can't access  the root folder

Tags: root, permissions

I do not have access to my root folder: Ubuntu says I do not have the necessary permissions to access it. I also cannot access `lost + found`, which gives me the same error message

Is there anyone here that can provide answers to these questions?

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson Probably not. It seems likely that this is asking about `/` (the root directory) rather than `/root` (root's home directory). Furthermore, this also asks about `lost+found` (which is always in `/` but never in `/root`, since in practice `/root` is one of the few top-level directories nobody puts on a separate filesystem.

Answer (score 21):

There are two different folders called the "root" folder: `/` (the [root of the filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory), which is really the only folder that should ever be called the "root folder"), and `/root` (the [root user](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser#Unix_and_Unix-like)'s [home directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory)). During the normal course of operation (i.e., except while performing administrative tasks), users cannot create new files in `/` or `/root`.

You should not change the [ownership or permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) of either directory (changing them for `/` in particular could break things very badly, perhaps even beyond creating security problems depending on what assumptions your applications and services make about the ownership and permissions of `/`).

If you have the `gksu` package installed, you can run `gksudo nautilus` to open a root-owned file browser window. If you do this, please be extra careful to only use it for tasks where you must be root, and to close it when you're done (so you don't later confuse it with an ordinary Nautilus window).

If you don't have `gksu` installed and don't want to install it, `sudo -i nautilus` or `sudo -H nautilus` are reasonably safe. (In contrast, if you were to use plain `sudo nautilus`, [you might have to fix some things](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application/270019#270019) in your home directory to get Nautilus to work properly again when you're *not* running it as root.)

However, **usually you don't need to do that either.** You rarely have to manually edit the top-level contents of `/` or the contents of `/root`. I recommend providng more information--or asking a new question--to explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish. The particular task you need to do will determine how you should proceed.

Finally, a note on `lost+found`. This [stores files recovered in filesystem repair operations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2115/whats-lostfound-and-where-did-it-come-from). Since such files could be from anywhere in the filesystem, it's necessary to require root permissions to access them (or any information on the system could potentially be accessed by someone who is not an administrator). If you think there may be files there that you wish to reclaim, you can check by running

```
sudo ls /lost+found
```

in a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

If there are files there that you want, then you can copy them out (and if their ownership and permissions don't give you the necessary access, change them). You can do that as root from the Terminal with [`cp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/cp.1.html), [`chmod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/chmod.1.html) and [`chown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man2/chown.2.html) (run as root with [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man8/sudo.8.html)), or with a root-owned Nautilus window as described above.

If you need to change ownership and permissions for files, then:

1. make sure not to do so for more files than necessary--for example, some people accidentally change ownership or permissions for large parts of the system and then have to reinstall, and
2. I recommend [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) for understanding the ownership/permissions system in Ubuntu (which also applies to most other [Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) OSes). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions) may help too.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, this is normal to Ubuntu and every Linux distributions. You can't access to the root folder because that folder is owned by root and it's user folder.

But, you can access that folder if you really want by using `sudo -i` command in the terminal. ***Be warned that, if you mess anything, it is your responsibility***.

Also using nautilus by Pressing **<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>** key and typing `gksu nautilus`

#### Changing permissions of root folder.

Assuming you want to change the permission of root user's home folder, which is `/root` folder, I would say, it is very bad idea to do so. Because, if you change the permission of root's home and you delete or modified some crucial file there, This may result in totally un-usable system. You may need to install Ubuntu from scratch.

But, if you really want it, the command is chmod:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /root
```

will let you gain access to the `/root` folder. See the manual page for [chmod command here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/chmod.1.html).

To learn more about File permissions, [Read this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)

Comment: Ok Thanks, but how can I change permissions so I can have access to those folders, what commands do I need or can you please provide a link for listed commands, I'm new to ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: @zanxt see my updated answer

Comment: Be aware that the security of Linux and Ubuntu relies on such things as not being logged in as root, and maintaining the permissions on system and root files as they have been set up.  There's really very little reason why you would need to get access to the root folder in normal use.  It is only there to provide compatibility with those processes that _do_ need to be root.

Comment: Even once someone has decided to change permissions on `/root` (a bad idea), they don't have to be `777`. Changing them to `770` and adding select users to the `root` group will let those users create, access, and modify files in `/root`. Alternatively, changing the group owner of `/root` to `sudo` will let administrators access it. All of these options are really bad and should not be done, but setting permissions to `777` for `/root` is probably the worst of them. **I understand your intention in presenting that method is *not* to advocate it, of course. I'm not disagreeing with you.**

Comment: I changed to 777 briefly for one task, but forgot to look at what it was before to revert it. What should I set it back to? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the following:

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` using `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Look for the line that says:

```
#PermitRootLogin yes
```

Make sure it looks like the below line:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

No hashes (i.e., #) and the yes is there.