# Revert /root/ user's home directory permissions

Tags: permissions, sudo, directory, root, chmod

When I realized that I did not have permission to access to the `/root` user's home directory, I followed the advice [from this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187997/i-cant-access-the-root-folder) which was to execute the command `sudo -i` (which I did) and then afterwards I executed the command `sudo chmod -R 777 /root` (which isn't the root of the file system).

With that being said, I wanted to revert my command `sudo chmod -R 777 /root` and `sudo -i` (whatever this one did...) to the previous and default permission (whatever that is) so I then executed the command `sudo chmod -R 755 /root`. Is the latter command the correct one to execute?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: `sudo -i` didn't really do anything in this context. However `sudo chmod -R 755 /root` doesn't really reverse your earlier command - in particular, it will leave any plain files unde `/root` with execute permission. Unfortunately there's no magic command to undo a recursive `chmod`.

Comment: @steeldriver, thank you for getting back to me! hmmm... I see. So, what will my “mistake” cost me? What will that do to my system, for example and is it big of an issue? What would you suggest in such a situation to remedy this situation (hopefully not reinstalling everything).