# Getting an error while mounting machine_config

Tags: 12.04, boot, partitioning, boot-partition, configuration-management

I am trying to boot my system but, it is giving me an error as

```
    "An error occurred while mounting home/jack/jack-app/machine_config "
            Press S skip to mounting or M for manual recovery
```

after this I restarted the system it worked fine. For troubleshooting this error I look into the `/var/log/boot.log`. Then I got the actual error as

```
mount: special device /machine_config/jack does not exist
mountall: mount /home/jack/jack-app/machine_config [601] terminated with status 32
mountall: Filesystem could not be mounted: /home/jack/jack-app/machine_config
```

So I tried to look into the `/machine_config` directory in that `jack` directory is not present. instead of it `Lost+found` directory is present. I don't know any reason how this directory is formed.

So I have following questions:

1. How this `Lost+found` directory formed.
2. If I created a directory as `jack` in the `/macine_config` folder is it causing any problem or any other solution for that problem
3. When I comment the issue line is it cause some problem to others.

Thanks in advance.

```
Here is my fstab file
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid   0     0




UUID=cb677870-6f0a-49bf-b6f6-0b6f25e7180f  /boot           ext4    sync,user_xattr,relatime        0      2


/dev/mapper/jack-logging         /var/log                 ext4    user_xattr,relatime             0      2
/dev/mapper/jack-machine_config  /machine_config          ext4    user_xattr,relatime             0      2
/dev/mapper/jack-videos          /videos                  ext4    user_xattr,relatime             0      2


/var/log/jack         /home/jack/video-jack-app/log             none    bind,nobootwait         0    0
/machine_config/jack  /home/jack/video-jack-app/machine_config  none    bind,nobootwait         0    0
/videos/jack          /home/jack/video-jack-app/video-output    none    bind,nobootwait         0    0


/dev/mapper/jack-swap      none            swap    sw                                0      0
```

Here is my output of **df** command

```
udev                                         1917840       4   1917836   1% /dev
tmpfs                                         772248     876    771372   1% /run
none                                            5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                                         1930620    2224   1928396   1% /run/shm
none                                          102400       0    102400   0% /run/user
/dev/mapper/jack-machine_config               11895    1132     10149  11% /machine_config
/dev/sda1                                   10321208  824604   8972316   9% /boot
/dev/mapper/jack-logging                   12385456  232180  11587052   2% /var/log
/dev/mapper/jack-videos                    30963708  178868  29211984   1% /videos
```

Comment: There is [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/2115/178596) for question **1.**.

Comment: You can try make new directory. But first, confirm that `/machine_config` is mounted. Run `df` to list all mounted paths. Please, add results of `df` to the question.

Comment: @Sneetsher, I have added output `df` command. please let us know your thoughts

Comment: Well `/machine_config` is mounted. If it wasn't, the new folder `jack` will be created in `/machine_config` folder which *does not point* to `/dev/mapper/jack-machine_config` . Now, try create new folder `jack` and change its owner and permissions same as  `/machine_config` . Please, let me know if i need to explain more.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the correct path is home/jack/video-jack-app/machine_config so missing video in the path shortened to home/jack/jack-app/machine_config throws an error as the path doesn't exist.

Neither of the options 2 or 3 you suggest will have the desired result, regarding #1 see the comment above by Wilf