# How do you recover item from lost+found?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

My /home partition usually contain two folders, one is named after my username and the second is lost+found. Somehow my folder named my username which contain all my files disappear, but I can find the content of it on lost+found folder. Unfortunately everything I can do is browse through them, I can't copy that file. How do you recover lost files from lost+found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may first want to know what `lost+found` is:

- [What's lost+found and where did it come from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2115/whats-lostfound-and-where-did-it-come-from)

The `lost+found` directory can only be accessed by the root user. So, to copy files, open a terminal<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and then do:

```
sudo su
```

to gain root access and then navigate to the `lost+found` directory.

```
cd /home/lost+found
```

then you can copy all recovered files to your home directory

```
mkdir $HOME/recovered\ files && cp -r /home/lost+found $HOME/recovered\ files
```

You will find all your recovered files in `recovered files` directory in your home folder.