# Remove files not required under lost+found directory

Tags: 14.04, disk-usage

My `lost and found` drectory has a large number of files, most of which are not needed.

But in the terminal when I try to use `cd`, it's asking for permissions and I'm not able to use `sudo`, since `cd` is not recognized as a command.

Hence I'm not able to delete the files which are not required - this is one of the reasons my root partition is showing full.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you recover item from lost+found?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/422525/how-do-you-recover-item-from-lostfound)

Answer (score 0):

`cd` is an internal command of your shell and can't be used with `sudo`

Use

```
sudo -i
```

to get a root shell. There you can use `cd`.