# What happened to the lost+found directory for 18.04?

Tags: 18.04

I'm just reading about how lost+found is/was used to store corrupted files that came out of system recovery. However, searching my computer i can only mklost+found files and what appears to be binaries of that name.

Was there a reason for removing this folder?

Comment: Please correct a possible typo in "*i can only **mk**lost+found files*".

Comment: lost+found has not been removed. It is still created if you are using e.g. ext4 file systems. Other types of file systems don't necessarily have lost+found folders.

Comment: How can I check the file system type I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

As before, the `lost+found` directory is present on any partition formatted with the ext file system. [See here on Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2115/whats-lostfound-and-where-did-it-come-from) to learn about its purpose.

`mklost+found` is a system command used to create such `lost+found` directory on an ext file system. Use the command `which mklost+found` to find out it is located in `/usr/sbin/`. See the man page for its purpose and how it is used (i.e.e, type `man mklost+found` in the termnal.

[Snaps and Flatpaks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866511/what-are-the-differences-between-snaps-appimage-flatpak-and-others) may add their own `mklost+found`, you you may find multiple such binaries on a linux system that supports Snap or Flatpak. On Ubuntu versions with snap support, you will find `mklost+found`executables associates with the `core` snap. The `org.gnome.Platform` flatpak also provides such a binary.